# Using Rob Hess's SIFT library in Ubuntu

Tags: opencv, gtk, computer-vision, ubuntu-10.10, sift

I'm trying to use Rob Hess's SIFT library in Ubuntu 11.10. SIFT along with its dependencies - OpenCV and GTK+ have been installed. Now, when I try to run from terminal any of the examples with the SIFT library, it terminates with "Illegal instruction". Could anyone help ? Thanks.